# C++: Function pointer to another class function

Tags: c++, function, pointers

I have 2 classes

```
class B {
public:
    int func(int i);
};

class A {
public:
    typedef int (B::*fPtr)(int);
    void run();
    B* mB;
};

void A::run() {
    // create a pointer
    fPtr p = &(B::func);
    // invoke the function
    mB->*p(2);     <------- Compilation Error
}
```

What i need is to create a pointer to func() in A's run function. I get a compilation error  saying that mB is not corresponding to a function with 1 argument.

please help

Comment: Why are you making this so complicated? Why have you tagged it with inheritance - when you are not using it? Have you heard of interfaces?

Comment: Why not use a std::function/boost::function? They tend to be much more flexible and much simpler to use than stupid C style function pointers.

Comment: @EthanSteinberg Member function pointers have little/nothing to do with C function pointers, and cannot be stored in `std/boost::function`

Comment: @BenjaminLindley It's trivial to store member function in a std::function. Example in this case would be `std::function<int(B*,int)> fun = &B::func`. Then the call would be a much less convoluted `fun(mB,2);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instance methods on a class always have a hidden first parameter for the `this` pointer, thus it is incompatible with your function pointer typedef.  There is no way directly to obtain a pointer to a member function.  The typical workaround is to use a "thunk" where you pass a static function that accepts a generic "catch all" parameter (such as `void *`) which can be statically cast to a pointer of your choosing on which you can invoke the member function. Example:

```
class B
{
public:
    static void MyThunk(void * obj)
    {
        static_cast<B *>(obj)->MyRealFunc();
    }

    void MyRealFunc()
    {
        // do something here
    }

    // . . .
};
```

You can get a pointer to the static function easily as it has no 'hidden `this`', just reference it using `B::MyThunk`.  If your function requires additional parameters, you can use something like a [functor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_object) to capture the necesssary parameters and state.

You should definitely read this C++ FAQ Lite page which tells you much more about all this: [Pointers to member functions](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/pointers-to-members.html)

Comment: Good answer.  Why does the type of `obj` have to `void *`?  I would prefer `B *`.

Comment: @bobbymcr: I take it that you have never worked with the `->*` and `.*` operators before?  They do allow calling methods on object instances via pointers, just as Alex's example showed.  He was ust missing a set of parenthesis to make his code compile correctly.

Comment: @DavidGrayson: Usually you have to use some "bare bones" pointer type to interop with things like `CreateThread` on Win32 which only lets you pass `LPVOID` to your `ThreadStart` function pointer.  You should of course make things as strongly typed as you can, but you don't always have a choice.

Answer (score 6):

You need to put parentheses around the function expression:

```
(mB->*p)(2);
```

But as others have pointed out, there's almost certainly a better way to do what you're trying to do.

Comment: First of all, thanks for the help. as for using other things mentioned above, I think that this solution is the most suitable one in my case

Answer (score 1):

why can you not call `mB->func(2);`?

If you need different functions for B perhaps look into `virtual` functions and class inheritance

Comment: Given my project design and the goal I want to achieve this is the solution I'm going for.